# Store date in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, date, datetime, prepared-statement

There is a lot of discussion here, but what I have tried isn't working. Till now in my tables I store the dates as a `string`, but I assume this isn't the right way... So I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TRANSACTIONS" (
    "date" DATETIME,
    ...
}
```

I want to store the date like `2016-11-04 10:50`, so I use:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

I use `prepared Statements` to insert records in DB and when I try to do this:

```
stm.setDate(1, timeStamp);
```

I get that `String cannot be converted to Date`. So I convert it to `DATE`

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date datee = formatter.parse(timeStamp);
```

and then I get `java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date` so I tried this:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(timeStamp);
```

which when I run it, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: You can use preparedStatement.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Date represents a date, not a date and time.
You are getting this error because you are passing `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` and throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

```
 String d1 = "2016-10-11";
 java.sql.Date d = null ;
 d.valueOf(date1);
 System.out.println(d.valueOf(date1));
```

`

This will run without any exception.
For your required format you should use `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
     String date1 = "2016-10-11 10:45";
     SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
     java.util.Date d2 = sm.parse(date1);
     Timestamp time = new Timestamp(d2.getTime());
     System.out.println(time);
```

Output - `2016-10-11 10:45:00.0`